# Exclude SSH Command Execution Status from Output

Tags: go, ssh

I am trying to develop a SSH client using Go language. I've written the below code to get commands from user, execute them on the remote server and print the response.

There's a small problem with the below code. Printing output on the screen prints the command execution status(nil/error status) at the end of response. How do I exclude this from my output?

**SSH.go**

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "io"
import "bufio"
import "os"
import "net"
import "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh"

func main(){

    sshConfig := &ssh.ClientConfig{
        User: "[USERNAME]",
        Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod{
            ssh.Password("[PASSWORD]"),
        },
        HostKeyCallback: func(hostname string, remote net.Addr, key ssh.PublicKey) error {
            return nil
        },
    }

    connection,err := ssh.Dial("tcp", "[IP]:[PORT]", sshConfig)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failed to connect: %s", err)
    }

    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)

    for{
        input, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
        session,err := connection.NewSession()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Failed to create session: %s", err)
        }
        stdout,err := session.StdoutPipe()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Failed to get stdout: %s", err)
        }
        go io.Copy(os.Stdout, stdout)
        output := session.Run(input);
        fmt.Println(output)
    }

}
```

**Current Result**

```
hello
Process exited with status 127
df -hP /tmp
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda6       198G   13G  176G   7% /
<nil>
```

**Expected Result**

```
hello
df -hP /tmp
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda6       198G   13G  176G   7% /
```

Comment: maybe you should redirect stderr to `/dev/null` ?

Comment: @armnotstrong - What would be the syntax for that?

Comment: @Beginner what if you put "redirect stderr to `/dev/null`" to google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<nil>` pinted above is the output of `session.Run`, which returns an `error` (as per [docs](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh#Session.Run)).

The output of the command is already being displayed on your console by the following goroutine:

```
go io.Copy(os.Stdout, stdout)
```

You don't need to print the `output`, which is `nil` since no error occurs when `session.Run` is call complete. A better thing to do would be to check the error:

```
// ...
if err := session.Run(input); err != nil {
  // handle error
}
// ...
```